# Laravel Eloquent Relationship on 2 tables related to 1 table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 Tables in my database. Candidate, Judges and Scores.

Now, What I want to do it to fetch or query or display the candidates that is not yet being scored by the judges.

in basic php we can query is using sql query like

`select * from scores where candidateId='1' and judgeId='2'`

Can anyone help me how to do it on Laravel Eloquent Relationship?

Comment: Show database diagram with existing relations.

Answer (score 2):

For this simple query, you don't need Eloquent Relationship, just do it with Model:

```
$scores = Score::where(['candidateId' => 1, 'judgeId' => 2])->get();
```

But if you want to do it with Relationship, you have to first define relationship in your Score model:

```
class Score extends Model {
    protected $table = 'scores';
    public function candidate() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Candidate::class, 'candidateId');
    }
    public function judge() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Judge::class, 'judgeId');
    }
}
```

Then you can query with the relationships:

```
$candidateId = 1;
$judgeId = 2;
$scores = Score::whereHas('candidate', function($query) use ($candidateId) {
    $query->where('id', $candidateId);
})->whereHas('judge', function ($query) use ($judgeId) {
    $query->where('id', $judgeId);
})->get();
```

**UPDATE #1:** 
If you want to get each candidates score, you can define relationship in your candidate:

```
class Candidate extends Model {
    protected $table = 'candidates';
    public function scores() {
        return $this->hasMany(Score::class, 'candidateId');
    }
}
```

Then find the candidate and its scores:

```
$candidate = Candidate::find(1);
$scores = $candidate->scores;
```

You can pass $candidate to your view and get scores inside view, but its not recommended to do query in your view. I mean do not call Candidate::find(1) inside your view, but $candidate->scores can be done inside view.

Comment: Thank you for this.. but how about if I already have controller for the Candidates and I just want to Do some query if this candidate has already a score or not yet.. Basically my idea is to do the query in views but I want it to do it inside the controller.. How is that possible?